navigationItem.title Issue
When navigating away from the view controller and subsequently returning, the custom titleView fails to reappear and not even visible in the view hierarchy, indicating a possible issue with the view's lifecycle management or navigation stack handling that prevents the titleView from being properly reinitialized or displayed.
func setTitleView() {
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44))
titleView.clipsToBounds = true
titleView.backgroundColor = .orange
self.navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = false
    
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
self.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(forTextStyle: .title)
self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.primaryBlackColor //UIColor.white
titleView.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
self.titleLabel.text = "adsvhjasjhdfgka"
}

I'm calling this function in viewDidAppear().your text

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
